# SVG viewBox to VML coordorigin/coordsize

Tags: svg, coordinates, vml, viewbox

I'm unsure how to convert the following SVG snippet containing a viewBox attribute to VML coordorigin and coordsize attributes.

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="-67235,-57840 124725,118547">`

Any help would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run this jsfiddle in IE<9 and see if it helps (you'll have to format the results).
http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/4ZWJd/

I don't know mutch about vml so I can't figure out how the transformations are made. You could just use Raphael.js directly since it provides a good abstraction over vml.